# Is there a quick way to replace column values in R?

Tags: r

Suppose we have a data frame containing numeric values which looks like:

```
Temperature Height
32          157
31          159
33          139
```

I want to replace `Height` values with `pic_00001`, `pic_00002` etc. so that the end result is:

```
Temperature Height
32          pic_00001
31          pic_00002
33          pic_00003
```

There are 10,000+ rows in the full data frame, hence I need a quicker way than doing this manually.

Comment: Why would you do this? After replacement, what is the relationship between original and sequential numbers?

Comment: The replacement is nonsensical in this example, I just needed the methodology so I could adapt it in my actual data set where it makes more sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`:

```r
# create the example used by the OP
dat <- data.frame(Temperature = 31:33, 
                  Height = c(157, 159, 139))

# use sprintf along with seq_len
dat$Height <- sprintf("pic_%05d", seq_len(NROW(dat)))

# show the result
dat
#R>  Temperature    Height
#R> 1          31 pic_00001
#R> 2          32 pic_00002
#R> 3          33 pic_00003
```

You can change the `05d` if you want more leading zeros. E.g. `07d` will give a seven digit sequence. The manual page for `sprintf` have further details.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
id <- seq_len(nrow(data))
new_values <- paste("pic_",id,sep = "")

data$Height <- new_values
```

Comment: I suggest replacing `seq(...)` with `seq_len(nrow(data))`; it seems innocuous, perhaps, but in automated/programmatic/unsupervised situations, if `data` has no rows, then *this* will error (`wrong sign in 'by' argument`, since `1` is greater than `nrow(data)`; the alternative of omitting `by=` is even worse, as that will produce a vector of length 2, which is almost never correct in this use. `seq_len` avoids all that.

Comment: Thanks! But small edit needed if possible - I need `pic_00001` instead of `pic_1`. @MonJeanJean

Comment: `paste(…, sep = '')` => `paste0(…)`. Good answer, although I’d write the whole thing in one line. I don’t think having a separate variable for `new_values` adds to the readability (nor does `id`, though to a lesser extent).

Comment: I suggest `sprintf("pic_%05i", id)` instead, it'll 0-pad it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(Height, ~ str_c("pic_", str_pad(row_number(), 5, "left", "0"))))

  Temperature    Height
1          32 pic_00001
2          31 pic_00002
3          33 pic_00003
```

Comment: Great - only issue is that the `Height` column contains some very long decimal places and these remain for some reason. For instance, one value now reads `pic_00231.424234`. Do you know how to amend this?

Comment: @HelpMePlease In the previous code `"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"` matches integer and possible numeric with decimals for your information. But it was not necessary to match at all.

Answer (score 3):

to achieve final output (from original by monjeanjean, i cant comment yet lol):

```
id <- seq_len(nrow(data))
new_values <- paste("pic_",formatC(x,width=5,flag="0",format="fg"),sep = "")

data$Height <- new_values
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I didn't know about `formatC()`. Nice one!