# Is it possible to shift column values up by one in R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose we have a data frame like this:

```
Value  Image
24.34  pic_00001
232.4  pic_00002
342.34 pic_00003
```

The `Image` column continues in the same sequence up to `pic_10000` in the full data set.

I'd like to replace the `Image` column values so that it starts at `pic_00002` - essentially deleting `pic_00001` and shifting them all up. The `Values` column should stay the same. In other words, the output should look like:

```
Value  Image
24.34  pic_00002
232.4  pic_00003
342.34 pic_00004
```

Up to `pic_10001` (which will need to be generated if the method is to shift all column values up by 1)

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Does the following work for you: `df$Shifted <- c(df$Image[-1], NA)`

Comment: If you need it to start at 2, then change (from your [previous question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68196537/3358272)) `sprintf("pic_%05d", seq_len(NROW(dat)))` with `sprintf("pic_%05d", seq_len(NROW(dat))+1L)`

Comment: Tidyverse's `lead()` seems useful too.

Comment: Does this answer your question: ["shift values in single column of dataframe up"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995257/shift-values-in-single-column-of-dataframe-up)? To be clear, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25691035) is likely the cleanest answer: `library(dplyr)` followed by your_`df %>% mutate(Image = lead(Image, n = 1, default = NA))`; I explicitly specified `n = 1` to illustrate a shift by 1, and `default = NA` to show the value used to fill the "stub" at the bottom of the column.

Comment: @Limey I actually meant to make it `lead()` rather than `lag()`, but I couldn't edit it in time, so I had to delete and retype. :/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `lead()` from dplyr.

```r
library(dplyr)

x <- tribble(
  ~value,   ~image,
  1,        "zero",
  2,        "one",
  3,        "two",
)

x %>% 
  mutate(lead_image = lead(image, 1, default = "manual three"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   value image lead_image  
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>       
#> 1     1 zero  one         
#> 2     2 one   two         
#> 3     3 two   manual three
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>